# How to auto/schedule archive email in outlook that meets certain criteria?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, rules

I want to archive/delete (on a schedule, so not just a one off thing) all email that meets a certain criteria, in specific:

- Older than 1 year
- Where my name is not in the To or Cc box
- Not sent to a specific distribution group

Any idea how I could set that up to run regularly?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about option 2 or 3, But you can certainly archive mails depending on the date. There is a feature called `AutoArchive` for that.

For Outlook 2010:
Click the File tab, and then click the Options tab on the File menu.
Click the Advanced tab.
Click AutoArchive Settings.

For Outlook 2007 and Outlook 2003:
On the Tools menu, click Options, and then click the Other tab.
Click AutoArchive.

Then to set folder specific settings, Right-click the folder that you want to AutoArchive, and then click Properties.
Click the AutoArchive tab.

Comment: I am aware of autoarchive by date, problem is that I don't want to delete emails that were sent to me, I only want to delete all of the 'chatter' emails.

Comment: Umm. Like we have `Chat` folder for gmail? Which mail service are you using?

Comment: The "Where my name is not in the To or Cc box" does not exist, however, there is the equivalent "except if my name is in the To or Cc box" in the rules Exception conditions